# after changes in CPUQuota my system became very slow

Tags: performance, cpu, memory-usage, cpu-load, cpulimit

I changed the CPUQuota=50% so that my system could use mimimum CPU resources but due to these changes my system became very very slow could anyone please help me to revert these changes and bring my system back to normal?

I ran below commands:

systemctl set-property user-1000.slice CPUQuota=50%

stress --cpu 3[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLWs.jpg)

Comment: What was the level set to before you changed it?   We don't have know what OS & release as you've not given us any clues as to that information, thus would be guessing currently.

Answer (score 0):

The command `systemctl cat user-1000.slice`, will show the default settings in the `/usr` files, followed by your modifications to them stored in files under `/etc`.  For example:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/10-defaults.conf
# ...defaults snipped...
# /etc/systemd/system.control/user-1000.slice.d/50-CPUQuota.conf
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Slice]
CPUQuota=50%
```

If this was your only modification to `user-1000.slice`, or if you want to revert all other changes of it to their default settings, type:

```
systemctl revert user-1000.slice
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! for your help. You saved my life I was about to reinstall ubuntu because of this issue. After systemctl revert user-1000.slice running this command my system is working great now :)